# Set width property on div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would have the same width DivTest and IdOtherDIV. 
I'm trying set property like this:

```
DivTest {
background: #007C52;
width: document.getElementById ("IdOtherDIV").scrollWidth + "px.\n";
}
```

Is any way to achieve it (IdOtherDIV is dynamically created and width can change on every page refresh)?

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: Is this code from a css file? It looks like you're mixing css and javascript together which is not possible like that. Could you give more information on where this code is located in your system?

Comment: do you have control over these dynamic divs ?

Comment: I have two divs and I would divs have the same width. but one of divs can change his width and i would the second get the same width like first. i haven't control over these dynamic div. this code which i entered is just sample, i'm waiting for better ideas

Comment: How dynamic is the `IdOtherDIV` div? Can it change width dynamically while the page is open? Or the width changes only on page reload?

Comment: "Can it change width dynamically while the page is open?" Yes, it can, but it should work only on page reload. this div has a sql report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery

```
width=$("IdOtherDiv").css("width");
$("#DivTest").css({"background":"007C52","width":width})
```